# 403 Forbidden returned when attempting to save to database

Tags: java, javascript, spring, hibernate, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to save/update several records at a time to my database (sql-developer) using Spring and Hibernate.  I pass my data via an ajax call through my controller, to the service layer, to the Dao, to a loop that iterates through my Hvo object list and decides if it's in the db already or not and then either saves a new record or updates a current record.  Once it goes through this loop (what looks like successfully) I get a 403 error and no alert on the page.  There is no error in my stacktrace in Eclipse.

Here is my javascript:

```
function saveLimXrefHvo(){

var list = []; 

//declare variables for the data pieces
$('#limAssigned li').each(function (index, li) {
var cdeBusUnit = $('select[name="cde_bus_unit"]').val();
var cdeRatingPlan = $('select[name="cde_rating_plan"]').val();
var cdeLimit = $(this).attr('id');
var txtLimitRptOcc = $('#textOcc').val();
var txtLimitRptCm = $('#textCM').val();
var uidMod = $('#saveRTnumberLimXref').val();
var numSortOrder = (index + 1);

//put the variables in the JSON object
var JSONObject = {
        "cdeBusUnit" : cdeBusUnit,
        "cdeRatingPlan" : cdeRatingPlan,
        "cdeLimit" : cdeLimit,
        "txtLimitRptOcc" : txtLimitRptOcc,
        "txtLimitRptCm" : txtLimitRptCm,
        "uidMod" : uidMod,
        "numSortOrder" : numSortOrder
};

list.push(JSONObject);

});
var dat = JSON.stringify(list);

$.ajax({
    type : 'PUT',
    url : 'saveLimXrefHvo.do',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : dat,
    success : function(){
        alert("This record has been successfully saved.");
    }
});//end ajax
```

}

Here is my controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveLimXrefHvo.do", method = RequestMethod.PUT,
consumes="application/json")

public void saveLimXrefHvo(@JsonParam(innerType=LimitXrefHvo.class) 
List<LimitXrefHvo> limitXrefHvoList) throws JsonParseException, 
JsonMappingException, IOException {

limitService.saveLimXrefHvo(limitXrefHvoList);
}
```

I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting the 403 error all morning now.  I tried changing up the Dao method by having a separate delete and separate save in the "else" portion of my loop and that didn't work.  Someone suggested to add the "consumes" in the controller method.  That didn't work either.  I'm open to suggestions, thoughts, questions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Spring controller know how to handle no response (i.e. `void`)?

Try returning back a JSON object that indicates a successful action.

**Example:**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Successfully saved... blah blah"
}
```

Implementation might look something like:

*Out of view (I added produces="application/json")

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveLimXrefHvo.do", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseMap saveLimXrefHvo(@JsonParam(innerType=LimitXrefHvo.class)  List<LimitXrefHvo> limitXrefHvoList) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException,  IOException {

    limitService.saveLimXrefHvo(limitXrefHvoList);

    return new ResponseMap("Success");
}
```

Comment: yes.  that was exactly it.  I added to my js dataType application/json and created a Response Map like so:  ResponseMap responseMap = new ResponseMap();
  responseMap.put("success", true);
  responseMap.put("message", "This record has been successfully saved.");

Comment: actually this is better:  return new ResponseMap("This record has been successfully saved.");

Comment: If you don't need the response body, annotate the said method with: @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) which would return HTTP 204 indicating success (but without a body).

Comment: @Jukka I like that option a lot